# How to correctly add javamail and activation dependencies to ant build.xml file?

Tags: java, ant, jakarta-mail

I try to send email using `JavaMail` and `activation` jars and compiling my project with `ant`.
Ant classpath looks like this:

```
<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="lib/javax.mail.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/activation.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="build/classes/"/>
</path>
```

Ant compile looks like this:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes/"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes/">
                    <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
            </javac>
            <copy todir="build/classes/">
                    <fileset dir="src">
                            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
                    </fileset>
            </copy>

</target>
```

But when I try to execute this (also using ant), it throws

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/mail/MessagingException

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that dependencies (javax.mail.jar and activation.jar) were not properly included in jar created by ant, so I created a fat jar, and after doing so everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add a `jar` to the classpath to compile the code, then you try the following `<javac>` and it will look like this:

```
<javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes">   
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="lib/javax.mail.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="lib/activation.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Comment: but what is the actual difference from my piece of code? Isn't it just first piece inserted in second?

Comment: He needs to add his first code inside `<javac>`. Check my code and his code.

Comment: it didn't help, still throws exception